# how to know in with framework some function are defined?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

ii need these functions :

```
_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop
_SecTrustEvaluate
_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop
_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback
_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName
```

but I can't find in with framework they are defined (I m not developing under xcode, so I need to know the framework name)

Comment: First Google hit for SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop is https://developer.apple.com/reference/systemconfiguration/1514899-scnetworkreachabilityunschedulef, which shows the framework name at the very top.

Comment: The first 2-3 letters generally denote the framework. `Sec` = `Security`, `SC` = `System Configuration`. `UI` = `UIKit` etc.

Comment: @Sulthan Except `SK` can mean `StoreKit` or `SpriteKit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you do:

1. Pick a symbol: `_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop`.
2. Remove the leading underscore. `SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop`
3. Go to the Apple API documentation at https://developer.apple.com/reference/ or in Xcode go to Window, then Documentation and API Reference.
4. Paste the symbol into the search field and select the matching symbol.
5. Look at the top of the reference page for the symbol. It shows what framework the symbol belongs to. In the case of `SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop` you see `SystemConfiguration`.

It's safe to assume that the others starting with "SCN" are also from that framework. This leaves `_SecTrustEvaluate`. Following the same steps you get `Security`.

You now know how to find the framework of any symbol.

Comment: thanks maddy, it's works ... but now i still have the error Error: "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:      _kFIRDefaultReachabilityApi in C:\Dev\FirebaseCore.framework\FirebaseCore(FIRReachabilityChecker_100546587526a7b619913bc63e6f40ce.o);

Comment: @Henry Are you trying to load OS X frameworks on Windows?

Comment: That's a completely separate issue from the one asked here. I'd post a new question with all relevant information about your issue building and linking your app. But first make sure you added the SystemConfiguration framework.

Answer (score 0):

SystemConfiguration framework (https://developer.apple.com/reference/systemconfiguration) and Security framework (https://developer.apple.com/reference/security) for SecTrustEvaluate.

Comment: Thanks Koen ! how you find this out ?

Comment: Google is your friend :)

Comment: This answer doesn't actually answer the question which is "how to know".

Comment: Well it answers "I need to know the framework name", but I agree, your answer is more complete.